# UIDocumentPickerViewController scrollview overlapping with top navigation bar

Tags: uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to show UIDocumentPickerViewController modally. Its showing but the scroll view inside UIDocumentPickerViewController is not showing some part from top, I have to scroll down to see the content, once released, again goes back to top. [image](see image).

This is how I am trying!

```
let documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.image", "public.audio", "public.movie", "public.text", "public.item", "public.content", "public.source-code"],
                                                                                          in: .import)

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true,
                     completion: nil)
```

Comment: Could you file a bug at bugreport.apple.com please? Looks like this is an issue with safe area insets not being properly propagated?

Comment: What is self here? Is it a top-level view controller? (This should not matter, but trying to understand where the bug is)

Comment: Yeah @ThomasDeniau, its the uiviewcontroller which presents the documents picker

Comment: Reported the issue at apple bugreport @ThomasDeniau.

Answer (score 1):

Setting uinavigation bar appearance globally to false solved the issue:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

but this still seems to be hack as it will affect other areas of app where the isTranslucent needs to be 'true'.

If someone finds a better solution please update. :)

Comment: Another observation, when I added this fix, now its working fine from top, but at bottom, some parts of scrollview is still hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, setting isTranslucent as false is work
And in order not to affect other codes, I set isTranslucent as the original value after call present.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).